# Converting bit to int in a "select *" query

Tags: mysql, sql, casting, bit

I query a big table (e.g. many columns) using a "select * from my_table"
some of the columns in my table are bit types, and I want to cast these specific columns to int. However, I want to keep my query as generic as possible, and hence don't want to name the specific fields that are bits.

Is there a way to achieve this? some how I envision something like select IF(is_bit(*,cast * as int, *), so that it does the same check for al fields and changes only those that are bits. I don't know if there is such a possibility in SQL. enlighten me please.

Comment: why do you want to cast them. the result is 0 or 1 from bitfield and you can also calculate with them. Or do you want to put more bitfields in one integer ?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and explain what you want your query to look like.  From what you say, you seem to want `sets` not bit fields.